# How to compare two arrays of objects and delete the duplicates in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, javascript-objects

So I have the following problem. I have two arrays of objects. Array1 contains many objects and Array2 contains a part of these objects:

```
array1: [{"first_name": "Wanda", 
          "id": 27, 
          "last_name": "Walhai"}, 
       
         {"first_name": "Victoria", 
          "id": 26, 
          "last_name": "Viperfisch"}]

array2: [{"first_name": "Victoria", 
          "id": 26, 
          "last_name": "Viperfisch"}]
```

And what I want to do is to delete all objects in array1 that array2 contains too (the duplicates). So the new array1 should look like this:

```
array1: [{"first_name": "Wanda", 
          "id": 27, 
          "last_name": "Walhai"}]
```

Can anybody help me to achieve this in javascript? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `id` a unique identifier?

Comment: @MinusFour yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Set` for all your identifiers and use it to filter out `id`s that show up on the other array.

```js
function filterById(mainArr, filterArr){
     let idSet = new Set(filterArr.map(obj => obj.id));
     return mainArr.filter(obj => !idSet.has(obj.id));
}
```

This will remove all objects in `mainArr` with a specific `id` that show up in `filterArr`.

Example here:

```js
let arr = [{
    "first_name": "Wanda",
    "id": 27,
    "last_name": "Walhai"
  },

  {
    "first_name": "Victoria",
    "id": 26,
    "last_name": "Viperfisch"
  }
]

let filterArr = [{
  "first_name": "Victoria",
  "id": 26,
  "last_name": "Viperfisch"
}]

function filterById(mainArr, filterArr){
     let idSet = new Set(filterArr.map(obj => obj.id));
     return mainArr.filter(obj => !idSet.has(obj.id));
}

console.log(filterById(arr, filterArr));
```

Comment: @Tönner yes sorry, I understood you wanted to remove the objects on the second array. Order was inversed, the example is fixed.

Comment: thanks so much for taking your time.. it works perfectly